# anemone print links on first page

Tags: ruby, anemone

wanted to see what i was doing wrong. here.

I need to print the links on the parent page, even they are for another domain. And get out.

```
require 'anemone'
url = ARGV[0]
Anemone.crawl(url, :depth_limit => 1) do |anemone|
    anemone.on_every_page do |page|
        page.links.each do |link|
            puts link
        end
     end
end
```

what am i not doing right?

Edit: Outputs nothing.

Comment: ok,what's the output of the code?

Comment: Can you show the command line command you hit in your console?

Comment: ruby crawl.rb http://www.stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me

```
 require 'anemone'
    require 'optparse'
    file = ARGV[0]
    File.open(file).each do |url|
      url = URI.parse(URI.encode(url.strip))
      Anemone.crawl(url, :discard_page_bodies => true) do |anemone|
            anemone.on_every_page do |page|
                    links = page.doc.xpath("//a/@href")
                    if (links != nil)
                            links.each do |link|
                                    puts link.to_s
                            end
                    end
            end

      end
    end
```